# Apply mean and sd to every column of data table

Tags: r

I have a data table with three columns: Accuracy, Specificity and Sensitivity. For each column I want to calculate the mean and sd of each column. I want the result be a data table with six columns (Accuracy.mean,Accuracy.sd, Specificity.mean, Specificity.sd,...). So far i did this:

```
test<-function(x){
  c(mean = mean(x),sd = sd(x))
}
b<-a[ ,lapply(.SD, test)]
```

With this i get two rows for each column.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please consider [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), thanks.

Comment: try `b<-a[ ,unlist(lapply(.SD, test))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close. Just use `unlist` over `lapply` and you are there.

```
b<-a[ ,unlist(lapply(.SD, test))]
b
#Accuracy.mean Accuracy.sd Specificity.mean Specificity.sd Sensitivity.mean Sensitivity.sd 
# 5.50000       3.02765         16.50000        3.02765      105.50000          3.02765
```

Its pretty straight forward with `dplyr` as:

```
library(dplyr)
summarise_all(a, .funs = funs(mean, sd))
#Accuracy_mean Specificity_mean Sensitivity_mean Accuracy_sd Specificity_sd Sensitivity_sd
#1           5.5             16.5            105.5     3.02765        3.02765        3.02765
```

Function created by OP

```
test<-function(x){
  c(mean = mean(x),sd = sd(x))
}
```

Sample Data

```
library(data.table)
a<- data.table(Accuracy = 1:10, Specificity = 12:21, Sensitivity = 101 : 110)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you explain me the reasons behind the usage of unlist? And how to make the result a data table

Comment: @costa_25 `lapply` will be called once for each column (3 times in your case). It will return a list with 3 items (each containing 2 leafs). By default it will coerced in 2 rows but `unlist` will make it 1 row. Try these two and you will understand: 1) `lapply(a, test) %>% as.data.frame()` 2) `lapply(a, test) %>% unlist()`